# Como o eclipse cria um projeto?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-link

> Quero entender como o eclipse gera um projeto

- **Quais pastas são obrigatórias dentro do diretório do projeto ? ex:
  src/**
- **Quais os arquivos que ele gera para indentificar que é um projeto
  eclipse ?**
- **Como criar um projeto eclipse sem utilizar a IDE?**

Comment: Esta pergunta parece ser fora do escopo.